# Swift compiler can't check for protocol type

Tags: swift, swift5, swift-protocols

On the following code:

```
protocol BananaProtocol {
    var banana: Bool { get}
}

class MyBanana: BananaProtocol {
    var banana = true
}

protocol BananaProvider {
    var provider: BananaProtocol { get }
}

class BananaProviderImpl: BananaProvider {
    var provider = MyBanana()
}
```

The compiler complains with the error: `Type 'BananaProviderImpl' does not conform to protocol 'BananaProvider'`

If I change to:

```
class BananaProviderImpl: BananaProvider {
    var provider = MyBanana() as BananaProtocol
}
```

It works.

Why can't the compiler infer that MyBanana is of type BananaProtocol since it's on the class signature? `class MyBanana: BananaProtocol`

I'd appreciate some help understanding this issue.
Thanks.

Comment: `var provider: BananaProtocol = MyBanana()` will also work.  It's possible (at a guess) that Swift is looking at `var provider = MyBanana()` and has decided to make it `var provider: MyBanana = MyBanana()` which obviously means that you're not implementing the requirements of the `BananaProvider` ‍♂️

Comment: From my point of view, Swift is very picky when it comes to typing. It has some expectations when it comes to defining these types and in most of these cases ```var provider: BananaProtocol = MyBanana()``` is most elegant, since you could use ```as``` in some scenario's to force a type. In my own projects, I very well almost always define the type for each variable, even when it is no spectacularly complicated situation. Looks nice and neat and actually prevents you from making coding errors when assigning new values or objects to these variables.

Answer (score 1):

A type that adopts a protocol is not the same thing as the protocol existential. (e.g. `MyBanana` is not `BananaProtocol`.)

Recommendation: never use existentials.

```swift
protocol BananaProvider {
  associatedtype Banana: BananaProtocol
  var provider: Banana { get }
}

class BananaProviderImpl: BananaProvider {
  var provider = MyBanana()
}
```

Comment: That's an interesting workaround for the problem, thanks. But could you elaborate on the "never use existentials" ?
Doing something like `var provider: BananaProtocol = MyBanana()` as suggested above seems like a perfect good solution. Thanks!

Comment: It's not that interesting—it's how things are generally done in Swift, because the code you show in the comment is actually not good at all! And it's too big a problem to talk about here. Existentials are generally worse than useless—they're not descriptive of the problem (e.g. try working with `BananaProtocol` instead of `MyBanana` within `BananaProviderImpl`—it's horrible UX), and have performance issues. Start here? https://forums.swift.org/t/improving-the-ui-of-generics/22814 See `SwiftUI.View` for the best example of where existentials are NOT used.